# verilog timing error happens in I2C design

Tags: verilog

When I am implementing a I2C slave, here shows a problem. My `sda` is an inout port. At time `164ns`, which is is area circled by red in the picture, the the slave writes `ack=1` to `sda`. After that, the testbench writes data to `sda`, and the slave SRAM reads from `sda`. 
However, seems that the area circled by red is also read by SRAM, which makes SRAM show 1 in MSB in blue denoted area. In practice, SRAM should read from the area after the red circled area. What might it be that causes this error?

[image]

part of the code shows below

```
READ_DATA:begin
    addr_x<=addr_x;
    ROM<=DATA_IN_ROM;      
    SRAM[SRAM_LEN-cnt]<=sda;  
end

READ_ADDR: begin // rw<=rw; 
    SRAM<=SRAM; 
    ROM<=DATA_IN_ROM; 
    addr_x[REG_LEN-cnt-1]<=sda; 
    cnt<=cnt+1; 
    sda_reg<=sda_reg; 
    sda_vid<=sda_vid; 
    freeze_cnt<= freeze_cnt; 
    freeze<=freeze; 
    rwcnt<=rwcnt; 
end
```

Comment: please press 'enter image description here' to see the picture

Comment: What is meaning of `ROM<=DATA_IN_ROM;`? Seems that you are filling SRAM bit-by-bit based on `cnt` value, so where is `cnt` value increment? Can you post some more code?

Comment: READ_ADDR: begin
    // rw<=rw;
     SRAM<=SRAM;
     ROM<=DATA_IN_ROM;
     addr_x[REG_LEN-cnt-1]<=sda;
     cnt<=cnt+1; 
     sda_reg<=sda_reg;
     sda_vid<=sda_vid;
     freeze_cnt<= freeze_cnt; 
     freeze<=freeze; 
     rwcnt<=rwcnt;
    end

Comment: Assuming you're inferring registers (based on you using `<=`, since there's not enough code to know), you don't need any `signal<=signal;` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your [duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425764/verilog-design-timing-issues) I believe that you are entering the `READ_DATA` state too early. Add another state (`ACK_R`) that go between `RW` and `READ_DATA`.

```
ACK_R: begin
  sda_reg <= 0;
  sda_vin <= 1;
  bus_state_next = READ_DATA; 
end
```

This will create a clock cycle where your ACK is performed without the SRAM reading the data. If you have set the ACK signal somewhere else, you should remove it. Your counter should now not count to 9, but to 8 instead. This should also be done for `ACK_W`.